# Is eyebrow hair loss common in hyperthyroidism?

Tags: hairloss, thyroid, hyperthyroid, eyebrows

I have seen many articles talking about hair loss in regards to *hypothyroidism* but very few about *hyperthyroidism*. People suffer from hair loss in both thyroid diseases, but is it common to lose hair from the eyebrows while on **carbimazole** for treatment of *hyperthyroidism*?

I mean both, hair loss because of the carbimazole or because of the hyperthyroid disorder.

Comment: Interesting... I have had hair and eyebrow loss during hyperthyroidism (stabilized after I started sleeping properly)... I wonder if there's evidence for this.

Comment: @DaveL Please explain what do mean by started sleeping properly. Before started sleeping properly what was your sleep pattern?

Comment: That added question about whether hair loss is reversible is making this question too broad in my opinion. Would you consider removing it?

Comment: @Totoro "Normally" as in average recommendation for humans... 7-9 hours. Before that, I was averaging 4-6 hours. I also slept at odd times such as 3am - 7am, 6pm to 10pm, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The condition that you're asking about is called in the professional terminology: "**madarosis**" (but see the picture that I attached). As many proffessional books states, it's common in hypothyroidism, and they don't say it about hyperthyroidism. Then it make sense that it's not *common* in hyperthyroidism. But in medicine always can be exceptions.

Regarding to the side effect of carbimazole, according to [this source](http://www.ehealthme.com/ds/methimazole/madarosis/) which rely on FDA report, there is no such side effect of carbimazole, and obviously it is not common as well.

> "Could Methimazole cause Madarosis? - from FDA reports
>
> There is no Madarosis reported by people who take Methimazole yet. We
>   study 2,148 people who have side effects while taking Methimazole from
>   FDA. Find out below who they are, when they have Madarosis and more.

Bibiligraphy:

1) Thyroid Disorders with Cutaneous Manifestations (p.129)

2) Illustrated Synopsis of Dermatology & Sexually Transmitted Diseases (p.384)

3) http://www.ehealthme.com/ds/methimazole/madarosis/

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ubiquitous Student (love your moniker!), the symptoms given in the image for hypothyroidism isn't completely right. Symptoms listed are found more with congenital hypothyroidism and/or more severe cases. It's true that cold pale dry skin is often one of the first physical change that *may* be detected but it's not always true for all individuals with hypothyroidism. I'm a case in point. When my hypothyroidism had worsened for an unknown reason after being treated and stable for years, my TSH level was 23.59 - no error was made either.

Comment: But even with my TSH that high, I was never cold nor was my skin dry. My mind was very foggy which worried me and I was always tired and lethargic. But my heart rate was around 80 bpm at rest. The only difference I noticed is I wasn't as bothered by the heat as usual during summer (and our summers are quite mild compared to most places). I'm considerably warmer than most women and I like cool temperatures. Only during sleep do I like being warm. I had hair loss - pretty bad actually - but my scalp and facial skin still stayed oily, just less than usual for me.

Answer (score -1):

usually in hypothyroidism eyebrow-thinning happens!which means eyebrow partial hair loss.
you can read more:

- http://press.endocrine.org/doi/abs/10.1210/endo-meetings.2016.THPTA.2.SUN-264
- http://europepmc.org/abstract/med/26457693

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). It's great that you included references in your answer, but generally link-only answers are frowned upon all across SE, mainly because if the links become inactive your answer becomes unusable, but also because the purpose of the website is not to redirect the OP to another site where they can read about their topic of interest, but to provide a specific answer and an explanation (supported by references as proof). Expanding a bit on your answer would add a lot to its value. Thanks!

Comment: My question is not about hypo.

Comment: hypo and hyperthyroidism has the same influence on hair.